# Displaying more obstacles with different position - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have more obstacles , but report is that it is a repeat .
I need to somehow simplify , but the problem is that with each obstacle must be clearly given position.
You do not know how?

This is code:

```
func createObstacle()
    {
        obstacle.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 620)
        obstacle.zPosition = 5;
        obstacle.name = "obstacle"
        obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: obstacle.size)
        obstacle.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        obstacle.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = collisionMask
        self.addChild(obstacle)
        obstacle2.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 400)
        obstacle2.zPosition = 5;
        obstacle2.name = "obstacle"
        obstacle2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: obstacle2.size)
        obstacle2.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        obstacle2.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = collisionMask
        self.addChild(obstacle2)
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you seem to be repeating yourself a lot, as you say.

So I would create a function that can setup a given obstacle. It takes the given obstacle along with a position input and returns a that obstacle with that position, as well as the constants.

```
func setupObstacle(obstacle:SKSpriteNode, position:CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode // You don't say, but I assume it is an SKSpriteNode..
{
    obstacle.position = position;
    obstacle.zPosition = 5;
    obstacle.name = "obstacle"
    obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: obstacle.size)
    obstacle.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    obstacle.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = collisionMask
    self.addChild(obstacle)
}
```

You can then call this from within your `createObstacle()` function...

```
func createObstacle()
{

    obstacle1 = setupObstacle(obstacle1, position:CGPoint(x:250, y:620));
    obstacle2 = setupObstacle(obstacle2, position:CGPoint(x:100, y:400));

}
```

I'm quite unfamiliar with Swift, but hopefully that's correct. I'm sure you get the idea anyway!

Comment: no problem... always fun to write something in a language you're not familiar with :P